# Continuous function and Topology.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ topological space and $A \subset X,$ $A$ is dense in $X$. Prove that if $F:X \to Y$ is continuous and constant in $A$, then $F$ is constant in $X.$

I solved it, but I want to show you just for check my solution.

Since $F$ is constant in $A$ we have $F(A) = \{c\}$, for some constant $c \in Y$, so $cl(F(A)) = cl\{c\}= \{c\}.$

We know that $ cl(A) = X$ because $A$ is dense.

It's easy to show that $F(cl(A)) \subset cl(F(A))$ because $F$ is continuous, so we have:

$F(X) = F(cl(A)) \subset cl(F(A)) = \{c\}.$

Comment: Why is $cl\{c\}=\{c\}$ though? This is not always true in general topological spaces. For example take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{0\},\mathbb{R}\}$. Then the closure of $\{0\}$ is the whole space.

Comment: Not only the proof but the statement to be proved breaks down if $Y$ is bad enough. If $Y$ has the indiscrete topology, then all functions $X\to Y$ are continuous.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Yes, true. Or if $X$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: @Mark What looks interesting here is that $T_1$ separation suffices for this proof, whereas the more general theorem, that a continuous map into $Y$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to  a dense subset of its domain, needs $T_2$.

Comment: @Mark If $X$ has the discrete topology, then $A$ will have to be all of $X$, so the result and the proof are still OK (though not interesting).

Comment: Ok, I don't know, how can I solve that???

Comment: You can't, because the statement is false. You need to assume $Y$ is at least $T_1$.

Comment: can you have a example??

Comment: Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology. Then any function from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous, including the indicator on $\mathbb{Q}$. So this is a continuous function which is constant on the dense subset $\mathbb{Q}$, but it isn't constant on $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarising the comments: For your (otherwise correct) proof to work we need that $\overline{\{c\}}=\{c\}$ for all $c \in Y$, i.e. $Y$ is $T_1$. You use this in in your final step of line 1 of the proof.

A non-$T_1$ counterexample is $X=\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology with $A=\mathbb{Q}$ (dense indeed) and $Y = \{0,1\}$ in the indiscrete (trivial) topology $\{\emptyset, Y\}$ and letting $f(x)=1$ for $x \in \Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ for $ x \notin \Bbb Q$. Then $f$ is continuous (all functions with codomain $Y$ are: we only check the sets $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset, f^{-1}[Y]=X$ are open) $f$ is constant on $A$ but not on $X$.

We can get a $T_0$ example by giving $Y$ the Sierpiński topology which has one dense singleton.